# Axios / Json for loop, How can I prevent this error?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

part of my code goes like this, URL is under for-loop.

> ```
>     axios.get(Url).then((response) => {
>       let getJsonAPI = response.data.data.products;
>       if (response.data.data.products.length > 0) {
>         state.jsonGetProductsAPI.push(getJsonAPI);
>       }
>     });
> ```

I'm getting this error because the response doesn't contain a  products property

I want to push the getJsonAPI only if there's a something inside the "data" tree. The code works as intended but there's an error and my OCD won't allow me to continue with the project :( Any ideas? I'm new to this stuff

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because undefined.length is throws error.

```
if (response && response.data && response.data.data && 
    response.data.data.products && response.data.data.products.length) {
    state.jsonGetProductsAPI.push(getJsonAPI);
  }
```

This code is not gonna throw error :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) syntax. It was designed specifically for cases like yours, so you could replace `a && a.b && a.b.c` with `a?.b?.c`:

```
axios.get(Url).then((response) => {
  const products = response.data.data.products;
  if (products?.length) {
    state.jsonGetProductsAPI.push(products);
  }
});
```

If there are cases where the response doesn't contain a `data` property, you should chain it optionally as well:

```
const products = response.data.data?.products;
```

Also note you don't need any polyfills, Vue will transpile it for you (into `a && a.b && a.b.c` syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You should check that `data` is present.
It is easier if you do all data checks at the top of the method and bailout (return or anything else that's acceptable) there.

```
axios.get(Url).then((response) => {
   if (!response.data || !response.data.data || !response.data.data.products) {
    return
   }

   // now you are sure that response.data.data.products is truthy

   let getJsonAPI = response.data.data.products;
   if (response.data.data.products.length > 0) {
     state.jsonGetProductsAPI.push(getJsonAPI);
   }
});
```

PS: errors should not be tolerated, it shouldn't be a matter of OCD.